# How to hide AddOLEObject when adding an embedded object [C#]

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have this line of code to add an embedded OBJECT in my word file:
The problem is when i add my excel file as an embedded object in my word, it's visible and i want to make hidden.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
 WordApp.Visible = false; // Here my word is hidden
 Document.Shapes.AddOLEObject("", "excelfile.xlsm"); // My excel file is not hidden it prompts me with a macro pop up even if my word is not visible.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a macro pop-up"? What kind of macros does the xlsm file contain? What is the purpose of embedding a macro-enabled excel workbook in the Word document? Why does the Word file need to be invisible? IOW, what end result are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am doing a homework for school. Basically i have a word document that writes two numbers  (macro included) in a text file and my excel worksheet will take the numbers (macro included) and calculate them to give me the output in a text file.

But my question is there a way to add an OLE object in a hidden window mode?
That's the macro pop-up (http://prntscr.com/qd78kl)